# MariaDB relationship

Tags: node.js, typescript, mariadb, sequelize.js

I don't really understand how works sequelize associations.
I have a MariaDB database with two tables: communes and code_postals.

[Database schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XADPC.png)

code_commune is *city_code* and code_postal *postal_code*. So, a city can have multiple postal_code and multiple cities can share the same postal_code.

My SLQ request must be something like this :

```
SELECT * FROM code_postals P INNER JOIN communes C ON P.code_commune=C.code_commune;
```

In my TypeScript data repository class I have this code:

```
const Communes = await this.db.define('commune', {
        code_commune: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        libelle_commune: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        }
    });
    const Postal = await this.db.define('code_postal', {
        code_commune: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        code_postal: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true
        }
    });
    // Define the relationship between the both tables
    Postal.hasOne(Communes,{foreignKey: 'code_commune'});
    Communes.belongsTo(Postal);
    return await Postal.findAll({include: Communes}).then((communes:any)=>{
        return communes;
    }).catch((e:any)=>{console.error(e);return false;});
```

I don't really understand the doc, differences between *hasOne, belongsTo, belongsToMany* etc methods and don't know how to make this association request.

elp me pleez

Comment: Firstly, Sequelize does not support composite primary keys so you need to add a surrogate primary key column (auto-generated) or use existing column with unique values (if you have any). And secondly please indicate what table is 1 and what table is N (I mean 1:N or N:1 relationship).

Comment: hi @Anatoly! Ok for pk. 
Both table are 1:N, you can check the shcema. A city can have multiple postal codes and a postal code can make reference to multiple cities.
For example, Paris have 20 postal codes : from 75001 to 75020 because this is a big city.  Fondettes, Luynes, Perany and Saint-Etienne-de-Chigny have the same postal code : 37230

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a certain city can have multiple postal codes and at the same time a certain postal code can be the same for several cities then you have M:N relationship between cities and postal codes and you need the third junction table like `CommunesPostalCodes`:

```js
const Communes = await this.db.define('commune', {
        code_commune: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        libelle_commune: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        }
    });
const Postal = await this.db.define('code_postal', {
        code_postal: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true
        }
});
const CommunePostal = await this.db.define('commune_postal', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.SERIAL,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        code_commune: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false
        },
        code_postal: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false
        }
});

// Define the relationship between the both tables
Postal.belongsToMany(Communes,{ through: CommunePostal, foreignKey: 'code_postal', otherKey: 'code_commune'});
Communes.belongsToMany(Postal,{ through: CommunePostal, foreignKey: 'code_commune', otherKey: 'code_postal'});
```

Comment: Yes thank you, I rebuild my DB model